# What's wrong with my TextView Layout Inflater?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to dynamically add TextView's to a LinearLayout, but I get an error and don't know how to fix it:

```
03-19 16:25:07.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:215)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
    at com.fincalc.financialcalculator.MainActivity.simulateDebtLifeSpan(MainActivity.java:220)
```

Here's the XML layout file that is being referenced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And my code for this problem:

```
 public void simulateDebtLifeSpan(CreditCard card){
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.simulatedminimumpayments,null);
    if (card.balance>0){
       -line 215- TextView sim = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.paymentrow,null);
        double newBalance =  card.getBalance()-card.getMinimumPayment(card.getBalance());
        sim.setText("Starting Balance: " + card.getBalance() + " Minimum Payment: " + card.getMinimumPayment(actBalance) + " New Balance: " + newBalance);
         ll.addView(sim);
         card.setBalance(newBalance);
         simulateDebtLifeSpan(card);
        return;
    }else {
        setContentView(R.layout.simulatedminimumpayments);
     return;
    }
}
```

Inflater's confuse me quite a bit still I have similar code that inflates table rows and then adds them to a table layout which works fine :/ could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.one_fifty_two_init, null);
```

If you're in an internal class, or other location (onTouchListener) etc.. which does not have access to the context (ie you can't use the keyword this) you can also try:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.one_fifty_two_init, null);
```

Oh and try wrapping your TextView in a linear Layout in it's XML.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
    ....your text view params
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My only thought is that maybe because your view isn't wrapped in a layout the inflator barfs.

Comment: thanks for that idea, I tried both ways but each one had a symbol that cannot be resolved. The inflater is in a method in the main activity, so I don't think that context is an issue. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try wrapping your textview in a LinearLayout in the xml file, that's my only other idea - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView sim = (TextView) View.inflate(this,R.layout.paymentrow,null);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and received the same error